# How to implement a timeout when using sync.WaitGroup.wait?

Tags: go, timeout

I have come across a situation that i want to trace some goroutine to sync on a specific point, for example when all the urls are fetched. Then, we can put them all and show them in specific order.

I think this is the **barrier** comes in. It is in `go` with `sync.WaitGroup`. However, in real situation that we can not make sure that all the fetch operation will succeed in a short time. So, i want to introduce a timeout when `wait` for the fetch operations.

I am a newbie to `Golang`, so can someone give me some advice?

---

What i am looking for is like this:

```
   wg := &sync.WaigGroup{}
   select {
   case <-wg.Wait():
   // All done!
   case <-time.After(500 * time.Millisecond):
   // Hit timeout.
   }
```

I know `Wait` do not support `Channel`.

Comment: Can you post how youre adding your wait groups and stuff like are you doing it through a loop or??

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If all you want is your neat select, you can easily convert blocking function to a channel by spawning a routine which calls a method and closes/sends on channel once done.

```
done := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
   wg.Wait()
   close(done)
}()

select {
case <-done:
// All done!
case <-time.After(500 * time.Millisecond):
// Hit timeout.
}
```

Comment: Has this pattern a name?

Answer (score 2):

Send your results to a buffered channel enough to take all results, without blocking, and read them in for-select loop in the main thread:

```
func work(msg string, d time.Duration, ret chan<- string) {
    time.Sleep(d) // Work emulation.
    select {
    case ret <- msg:
    default:
    }
}

// ...

const N = 2
ch := make(chan string, N)

go work("printed", 100*time.Millisecond, ch)
go work("not printed", 1000*time.Millisecond, ch)

timeout := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
loop:
for received := 0; received < N; received++ {
    select {
    case msg := <-ch:
        fmt.Println(msg)
    case <-timeout:
        fmt.Println("timeout!")
        break loop
    }
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/PxeEEJo2dz.

See also: [Go Concurrency Patterns: Timing out, moving on](http://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and).

Comment: Not sure why a non-blocking send is needed here, unless it's only a safety measure in case buffer size doesn't match number of workers. Otherwise counting (proposed for loop) is most probably a better solution than `WaitGroup` when workers are producing something on a channel.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to monitor it internally, your question is limited but I'm going to assume you're starting your goroutines through a loop even if you're not you can refactor this to work for you but you could do one of these 2 examples, the first one will timeout each request to timeout individually and the second one will timeout the entire batch of requests and move on if too much time has passed

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    success := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go func() {
        // send your request and wait for a response
        // pretend response was received
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        success <- struct{}{}
        // goroutine will close gracefully after return     
        fmt.Println("Returned Gracefully")
    }()

    select {
    case <-success:
        break
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        break
    }

    wg.Done()
    // everything should be garbage collected and no longer take up space
}()

wg.Wait()

// do whatever with what you got    
fmt.Println("Done")
time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
fmt.Println("Checking to make sure nothing throws errors after limbo goroutine is done")
```

Or if you just want a general easy way to timeout ALL requests you could do something like

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
waiter := make(chan int)
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    success := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go func() {
        // send your request and wait for a response
        // pretend response was received
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        success <- struct{}{}
        // goroutine will close gracefully after return     
        fmt.Println("Returned Gracefully")
    }()

    select {
    case <-success:
        break
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        // control the timeouts for each request individually to make sure that wg.Done gets called and will let the goroutine holding the .Wait close
        break
    }
    wg.Done()
    // everything should be garbage collected and no longer take up space
}()

completed := false
go func(completed *bool) {
    // Unblock with either wait
    wg.Wait()
    if !*completed {
        waiter <- 1         
        *completed = true
    }       
    fmt.Println("Returned Two")
}(&completed)

go func(completed *bool) {
    // wait however long
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    if !*completed {
        waiter <- 1         
        *completed = true
    }       
    fmt.Println("Returned One")
}(&completed)


 // block until it either times out or .Wait stops blocking 
 <-waiter

// do whatever with what you got    
fmt.Println("Done")
time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
fmt.Println("Checking to make sure nothing throws errors after limbo goroutine is done")
```

This way your WaitGroup will stay in sync and you won't have any goroutines left in limbo

http://play.golang.org/p/g0J_qJ1BUT try it here you can change the variables around to see it work differently

Edit: I'm on mobile If anybody could fix the formatting that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to avoid mixing concurrency logic with business logic, I wrote this library https://github.com/shomali11/parallelizer to help you with that. It encapsulates the concurrency logic so you do not have to worry about it.

So in your example:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/shomali11/parallelizer"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    urls := []string{ ... }
    results = make([]*HttpResponse, len(urls)

    options := &Options{ Timeout: time.Second }
    group := parallelizer.NewGroup(options)
    for index, url := range urls {
        group.Add(func(index int, url string, results *[]*HttpResponse) {
            return func () {
                ...

                results[index] = &HttpResponse{url, response, err}
            }
        }(index, url, &results))
    }

    err := group.Run()

    fmt.Println("Done")
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Results: %v", results))
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err) // nil if it completed, err if timed out
}
```